# Display number of assertions in python unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertions

phpUnit displays the number of tests run, and the number of assertions made. The way I currently execute python's unit tests, only the number of tests run is displayed. Is there a way to also count the number of assertions?

Comment: Run your tests with `--help`, you'll learn a few useful bits, including how to get more detailed stats.

Comment: @9000: Uh, I like the --verbose flag. It doesn't quite do what I set out to do, but it will come in handy some other time!

Comment: @DudeOnRock I also have the same question with you, I want to obtain the  assertions statistics in python unittest not only the cases numbers. How can I achieve this ? Hope you reply, thanks.

Comment: @DudeOnRock I second this. `unittest` for C(-like) programs prints all kinds of interesting stats. Sadly, it seems like this is simply not supported in the python version.

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to run your tests with pytest, it can count the assertions for you.

There is a [hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_assertion_pass) you can implement in your `conftest.py` file that gets called for every passing assertion. You could count the number of times that gets called, and then print that out in the summary. That won't count calls to `unittest.TestCase.assert...()` functions, only `assert` statements.

To enable the hook, write a `conftest.py` file like this:

```
assertion_count = 0


def pytest_assertion_pass(item, lineno, orig, expl):
    global assertion_count
    assertion_count += 1


def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    print(f'{assertion_count} assertions tested.')
```

Then enable the hook in your `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
enable_assertion_pass_hook=true
```

You might also find the [assertion compare hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_assertrepr_compare) useful.

After all that, I'm not sure that the number of assertions is a reliable measure of test quality. You might want to look into mutation testing with [MutPy](https://pypi.org/project/MutPy/) or [mutmut](https://pypi.org/project/mutmut/).

Comment: Thank you! Precise and works. I put the `conftest.py` and `pytest.ini` inside the same folder as the tests and I had to delete the `__pycache__` folder in that folder to make it work, else it will print `0 assertions tested.`.